# NFT minting - Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]

Tags: solidity, etherscan

I was encounter this during mint . from what i google , its seem more rlevant to minter (msg.sender) gas limit too low and cause this issue.

However ,there are still not working to increase gas limit from 300,000  increase to 1,000,000

I doubt on anything can fix from solidity logic or code ?

kindly refer to below txn

[1]
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaf7c1261113b97f4ddb5a147a4d4031a860686ee236e99d90367988e6231ac92

[2]
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3aaa007d4367cbb658160da9e3b184fadd30a56b317f797b43d9e4d39054c838

[3]
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7e35d4cd1da9b771da7e2e62f524aafd7c30074f15e8fe89a1a44382ae9ecef6

below is sol

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(!paused, "the contract is paused");
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(_mintAmount > 0, "need to mint at least 1 NFT");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "max mint amount per session exceeded");
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(onlyWhitelisted == true) {
            require(isWhitelisted(msg.sender), "user is not whitelisted");
            uint256 ownerMintedCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
            require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= nftPerAddressLimit, "max NFT per address exceeded");
        }
        require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "insufficient funds");
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }
```

Comment: 300k or 1m gas ? Have not checked your code, but this is A LOT. Are you sure it is optimized ? If yes, are you sure this is something that cannot be done anywhere else ? You (or your users) are going to pay a lot for this.

Comment: Hi Sir, I not sure wtheter due to solidity coding or anything else. yes current one of project facing this error . i can txn gas limit increase from 300k to 1 m and yet still failed .

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have much time right now to see the actual problem, but I can say that `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]` isn't the reason why the contract is failing. It is just something that is caused by the real problem.

And the real reason is here:

[image: fail]

`Fail` isn't really descriptive, so you should go through the code and see if you are missing something.